# Reading directly from a FILE buffer

Tags: c, linux, glibc

The core of my app looks approximately as follows:

```
size_t bufsize;
char*  buf1;
size_t r1; 
FILE* f1=fopen("/path/to/file","rb");
...
do{
  r1=fread(buf1, 1, bufsize, f1);
  processChunk(buf1,r1);
} while (!feof(f1));
...
```

(In reality, I have multiple `FILE*`'s and multiple `bufN`'s.) Now, I hear that `FILE` is quite ready to manage a buffer (referred to as a *"stream buffer"*) all by itself, and this behavior appears to be quite tweakable: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Controlling-Buffering .

How can I refactor the above piece of code to ditch the `buf1` buffer and use `f1`'s internal stream buffer instead (while setting it to `bufsize`)?

Comment: You should not try to do this. Use `fread` or `fgets`

Comment: What is the motivation for this ? Any kind of hack that you might use is going to be unreliable, non-future-proof and non-portable.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @'Paul R': 1) Intellectual curiosity 2) I need to be keeping track of multiple FILE*'s at once, and of multiple buffers at once, and if FILE* already had a pointer to a buffer, it seems it would make things simpler. 3) Having a buffer in FILE and a buffer in my code seems to imply unecessary in-memmory copying (sure--if I'm reading from a HDD, the copying will be practically instantaneous in comparison to HDD io, but still) 3) see 1) ;)

Comment: Controlling a loop with `feof` is almost certainly wrong. For example if a read error occurs, end-of-file will never occur, yet reads will happily fail

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want opaquely buffered I/O, don't use `FILE *`. Use lower-level APIs that let you manage all the application-side buffering yourself, such as plain POSIX `open()` and `read()` for instance.

Comment: He actually seem to want buffering: "use f1's internal stream buffer instead".

Answer (score 0):

So I've read a little bit of the C standard and run some benchmarks and here are my findings:

1) Doing it as in the above example does involve unnecessary in-memory copying, which increases the user time of simple `cmp` program based on the above example about twice. Nevertheless user-time is insignificant for most IO-heavy programs, unless the source of the file is extremely fast.
On in-memory file-sources (`/dev/shm` on Linux), however, turning off `FILE` buffering (`setvbuf(f1, NULL, _IONBF, 0);`) does yield a nice and consistent speed increase of about 10–15% on my machine when using buffsizes close to `BUFSIZ` (again, measured on the IO-heavy `cmp` utility based on the above snippet, which I've already mentioned, which I've tested on 2 identical 700MB files 100 times).

2) Whereas there is an API for setting the `FILE` buffer, I haven't found any standardized API for reading it, so I'm going to stick with the true and tested way of doing, but with the `FILE` buffer off (`setvbuf(f1, NULL, _IONBF, 0);`)

(But I guess I could solve my question by setting my own buffer as the FILE stream buffer with the _IONBF mode option (=turn off buffering), and then I could just access it via some unstandardized pointer in the FILE struct.)

Comment: Might be useful for other prematurely optimizing idiots like me.